# Eclipse RCP Development - Slowness during debug

Tags: debugging, eclipse-rcp, macos-sierra

I have been using Eclipse (Oxygen or 4.7) to build an Eclipse RCP App in MacOs Sierra.

When I stop the execution with a breakpoint, IDE is really slow. After moments, it logs following statements to error console.

Have you guys seen this? Any workaround to overcome this?

```
    2017-09-18 15:39:49.814 java[5621:1677726] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (19.02 secs).
    2017-09-18 15:39:49.817 java[5621:1677726] *** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteView informAuxServiceOfSelf], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-283/NSRemoteView.m:3207
    2017-09-18 15:39:49.827 java[5621:1677726] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : [self textInputContext]=0x7ff8de18e840 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=com.apple.ViewBridge Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.apple.ViewBridge.error.hint=__38-[NSRemoteView _advanceToConfigPhase:]_block_invoke.2466 caught NSInternalInconsistencyException '<NSRemoteView: 0x7ff8ddebe6f0> failed to rendezvous via aux service' with backtrace (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9ebc92cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffb39d448d objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9ebce042 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fffa0616c80 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
        4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fffb242ab34 -[NSRemoteView informAuxServiceOfSelf] + 345
        5   ViewBridge                          0x00007fffb242b47e -[NSRemoteView _finishAdvanceToConfigPhaseWithContextID:andServiceViewSize:andOffset:] + 685
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, then I have bumped up to 10.13.1 (17B48), MacOS High Sierra. Now the performance is smooth as before. I hope this solves your problem too.

Comment: Thank you. Will try to upgrade to High Sierra and see how it goes.